# How to extract system specific data from UEFI BIOS? (MAC address, SN, UUID, MSDM key, etc.)

Tags: boot, bios

I’ve been looking and asking about this in forums and all around the Internet.

My laptop is dead. It’s stuck in a boot loop after changing boot settings and now I can’t use it. Asking around, I found that my BIOS was corrupted.

Anyways, I already dumped the .bin file from the chip. What I’m looking for is the system specific data to transfer it to my new BIOS file. I have almost no experience with hex files or bios files in general, so I don’t know what to look for.

Is there a tool for editing this kind of file? Or is there a way to look for this information in the code?

Fortunately, I took a picture of the main bios screen and I have my SN and my UUID, so I may be able to crosscheck with the bios file, but I don’t know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What makes you think this will fix the problem of boot looping? Dinking with bios files is dangerous, it could brick your pc permanently.

Comment: Hi, I'm still open to suggestions on how to repair my PC. please let me know if you have one @Moab

Comment: Remove the hard drive, then see if you can get into the bios.

Comment: Have you tried telling BIOS to use all Default settings? This usually will do the trick. I usually write all my settings down, or if BIOS has a _Save My Default..._ I will use that, __before__ tinkering with any BIOS settings, except maybe adding a hard disk or SSD. Good Luck

Comment: I already tried that

Comment: @vssher how can I do that? I can't get into the bios, it boot loops after ~2 seconds

Comment: Like Moab suggested take out your hard drive and press and hold down your BIOS key on the keyboard while it boots.

Comment: I already tried removing the hard drive, reseating ram, using a new ssd, pressing the bios button when booting, crisis recovery (I don't know if that was compatible with my pc but I still tried that), and it still doesn't boot :( . Thank you for your suggestions anyways

Comment: Is it possible?, maybe, that you messed up your RAM or something else, inside the laptop while you  were playing or discovering with it? Remove your battery to the power, open it up and then remove the small 3 volt battery inside, leave it alone for about 20 minutes, you might want to put a new battery in its place so you won't have to go through that for a while, then put it all back together, carefully. Then try it out.

Comment: I don't think anything is messed up. It happened immediately after turning off secure boot and rebooting, and I hadn't opened my laptop prior to that (except for cleaning, about a year ago). And I already tried resetting the cmos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool named [UEFITool](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/uefitool.html) for this.

It can parse BIOS/UEFI images, It can open and edit UEFI images from BIN and EFI files. You can use it to both extract data and modify it.

Comment: Gee, I hope this person does not use this tool, he messed up just playing inside the BIOS, never mind editing it....

Comment: @vssher he asked for a tool to edit BIOS bin files  and fixing his BIOS is out of scope for this thread.

Comment: Thank you @WasifHasan

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with FD44Editor on Asus boards.  For other manufacturers it's sometimes at Hex position 1000 in a hex editor like HxD. If you have a record of your MAC address (like from router logs, or a sticker on your motherboard) you can try searching the hex value in a hex editor.

I'm currently on the same crusade, and will update my answer if I find it!